# Uncaught Error when using Angular Factory to provide API calls

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a service to give my application full access to every single API resource available from a single service. Right now I have created my main Angular app module and an API service called APIService. The service has a factory that returns a number of accessible Angular `$resource`'s to the different APIs. Here is the code.

```
 var app = angular.module('MYAPP', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'apiService']);


    var APIService = angular.module("apiService", ["ngResource"]);
        APIService.factory("API", function ($resource) {
               var apiFactory = {};

               apiFactory.Alerts = $resource('/WebApi/Alert/:type/:id', {id:'all'},
                {
                    systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                    autoArchive: { method: 'POST', url: '/WebApi/Alert/Template/:type' }
                });

               return apiFactory;
           });
```

However, when I try to load the page, I get an `Uncaught Error` within the angular.js file. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Chrome, b/c that pesky "Uncaught Error" message. There's a real, longer error message that Chrome is hiding from you. Try FireFox and see if you get a better, more useful error message :)

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to define a function inside your object:

```
     apiFactory.Alerts = function(){

         return $resource('/WebApi/Alert/:type/:id', {id:'all'},
            {
                systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                autoArchive: { method: 'POST', url: '/WebApi/Alert/Template/:type' }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to use a function? I don't want apiFactory.Alerts to be a function, I want it to actually be a $resource so I can access the $resource with something like `API.Alerts.query()`

Comment: So return yout $resource , where I wrote you can return whta ever you want !
I'll edit

Comment: If you dont want to use a function, you have to go for other servises , there are lots of them in angular , Search fo searvises in angular.
But factory will do the job